# How to get frame numbers from video in android?

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

Is there any way for getting the total number of frames from a video in android? I'm using `com.github.wseemann:FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever:1.0.14` library for getting a frame on specific time. In order to get frames and save them as an image with specific time intervals, I need to get frame numbers.

Comment: What did you try to do so far?

Comment: Now I can get number of frames but can not get frames by specific time
        FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new 
        FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever();

        try {
            //path of the video of which you want frames
            mmr.setDataSource(absolutePath);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception= "+e);
        }
        long duration = mmr.getMetadata().getLong("duration");
        double frameRate = mmr.getMetadata().getDouble("framerate");
        int numberOfFrame = (int) (duration/frameRate);

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for getting frame numbers and frame rates using FFmpeg library. If anyone is struggling with frame extraction, you can refer to https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever. Below is my code to get the total number of frames.

```
FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever();

try {
    //path of the video of which you want frames
    mmr.setDataSource(absolutePath);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Exception= "+e);
}
long duration = mmr.getMetadata().getLong("duration");
double frameRate = mmr.getMetadata().getDouble("framerate");
int numberOfFrame = (int) (duration/frameRate);
```